# Why are values with priority = 50000 getting placed before values with priority = 10000? (SORT: ASC)

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following order by clause in my sql query statement:

`ORDER BY CASE WHEN priority IS NULL THEN 10000 END, priority, id`

I had purposefully set some records to have priority 50000, so they would appear at the end of the query.

However, these records are returned (immediately) before the NULL values, even though the null values should have a value of 10000 according to the `CASE` clause.

Example (output):

```
priority 1 record
priority 2 record
priority 50000 record
priority NULL record
priority NULL record
(only null records after this)
```

What I want:

```
priority 1 record
priority 2 record
priority NULL record
priority NULL record
.
.
.
priority 50000 record
priority 50000 record
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `catalog` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `author` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `rate` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 20,
  `retail_price` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `stock` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Show us your exact `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Comment: @Phil No, I do not want the records with priority=NULL coming first, I want them to come in between according to specific conditions.

Comment: @Dai I've updated it.

Comment: @Neptune my apologies, I misunderstood the result

Comment: your existing order by orders by three expressions; the first takes precedence; only if it is different are the second and third checked.  and your first expression is either 10000 (when priority is null) or null (all other cases, because no WHEN clause was satisfied and there was no ELSE).  this is clearly not what you meant; you seem to be expecting an `ELSE priority` to be implied, but you have to explicitly say that if you want a non-null ELSE value (and `COALESCE(priority,10000)` is equivalent to `CASE WHEN priority IS NULL THEN 10000 ELSE priority END` but much shorter anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to [*coalesce*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) the `priority` to a default value

```sql
ORDER BY COALESCE(priority, 10000) ASC, id ASC
```